# Is there any situation when there's no alternative to instanceof?

Tags: object-oriented, ruby

It seems to me that `instanceof` comes from the land of functional programming and is a watered down version of *pattern matching* and that the OO altenative to it should be dynamic dispatching.

In OO languages (think Ruby), is there any situation where `instanceof` is the only solution? I can't think of any myself, especially in Ruby where you can patch any class with any methods you like.

Comment: Either you're misusing the term "functional programming" to refer to "procedural programming" (I kid you not, I've seen this happen), or your impression is wrong. Many functional programming languages don't even have a (easily accessible, widely used) equivalent to `instanceof`.

Comment: "Many functional programming languages don't even have a (easily accessible, widely used) equivalent to instanceof" But, but, Haskell, Scala and ML have pattern matching which is even better than `instanceof` and Scheme and Racket have ways to easily check if something is of a specified struct/record

Comment: Ah yes, there's something else that seems off to me. Algebraic data types and pattern matching is quite different from OO subtyping and `instanceof`, both in theory and in practice. Look up the expression problem for a good example of how it shows; it comes down to ADTs having only a finite, well-known set of alternatives while one can always add new subclasses. Apart from that, I'm confident that the idea of `instanceof` was not literally taken from FP. It's a simple idea that one can arrive at independently, starting from the general idea of Java-style OO.

Comment: @delnan: If you have an algebraic data type which is the sum of different subtypes, you can add a new alternative at any time like you can add a new subclass to a given class. Regarding `instanceof`, I agree that it is not the OOP way of dispatching on different types. The OOP way is rather dynamic dispatch. `instanceof` is a procedural / functional approach that has been added to several OOP languages as a facility (the OOP solution can get very verbose).

Comment: @Giorgio I don't follow. With an algebraic data type, the alternatives (constructors) are enumerated in one place and cannot be affected by other modules. Any time an algebraic data type is used, the compiler (and you, if you bother opening one additional file) the exact set of possible constructors. With subtype polymorphism, new subtypes may be created in any module, even in dynamically (runtime) loaded code, and passed around to any code operating on the supertype.

Comment: @delnan: Ah, ok, you meant extending the type later. Yes, you are right. In the functional paradigm it is more complex to extend types (you have to change all the functions using the type and handle the new alternative). Similarly, in the object-oriented case it is tricky to add new operations to a given type: when adding a new method to an interface you have to extend all classes implementing that interface. Bottomline: I agree with you that extending types is more difficult in the functional approach, but nothing prevents you from extending an ADT if you need to.

Answer (score 6):

The usual argument for avoiding `instanceof` is "Instead of checking the type of a thing to decide on an action, you should make that action a method of that thing, and use inheritance to ensure that every thing automatically does the right thing." In other words, use the method look-up mechanism built into the language rather than program your own.

However, that usually is restricted to *single dispatch*: selecting an action based on the exact type of *one* participant. If there are two or more participants with varying types, it simply doesn't work, because most languages only have single dispatch built in. You can sometimes rearrange things so that the two participants become arguments to a method on a third one and use method overloading, which does support selection based on several parameter types, but (again, usually) only when the alternatives aren't subtypes of each other. It may also also be resolved at compile time rather than at run time, which subtly changes the semantics of your program.

That is by no means the only thing that `instanceof` makes possible, but in my view the most relevant one.

Comment: Well, there is the visitor pattern...

Comment: +1 for mentioning dynamic dispatch, single and multiple dispatch. "In other words, use the method look-up mechanism built into the language rather than program your own.": I think the argument in favour of this solution is that this is the object-oriented solution. Of course, if you need multiple dispatch and your language does not provide it, you need something like the visitor pattern, as delnan pointed out. So I think the main criticism against `instanceof` is that it is not object-oriented, where object-oriented means "based on dynamic dispatch".

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where `instanceof` is unavoidable. This applies to languages, where a class can be closed. For example, in Java there can be final classes. You can't inherit from them, nor can you make such a class implement an interface of your own.

An example case would be to have a list containing Integer and Double objects and you want to do different things based on the type.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. In a language that supports interfaces (either explicitly, or in the form of multiple inheritance with pure virtual classes, like C++), you can always use the following pattern:

```
interface Fooable {
    void foo();
}

abstract class BaseBaz {
    public abstract Fooable asFooable();
}

class BazOne extends BaseBaz {
    public Fooable asFooable() { return null; } // not a Fooable!
}

class BazTwo extends BaseBaz implements Fooable {
    public void foo() { Console.print("I am teh foobar!"); }
    public Fooable asFooable() { return this; }
}

// --- snip ---

void runFooOnBaz(Baz baz) {
    Fooable fooable = baz.asFooable();
    if (fooable == null)
        throw new NotFooableException();
    fooable.foo();
}
```

That is, you approach each object by interface, and give the base class a method to return you the object by interface if possible. (There is probably a name for this pattern, but I don't know it - if anyone knows, feel free to edit.)

In a duck-typing language like Python, you'd go a different route: rather than asking whether the object inherits from a given class, you just pretend it does and prepare for failure:

```
class BazOne(object):
    pass

class BazTwo(object):
    def foo():
        print "I am teh foobar!"

def runFoo(baz):
    try:
        baz.foo()
    except AttributeError:
        raise NotFooableError()
```

However, the latter isn't *always* possible; reasons as to why not include:

- You might rely on more than one method, and the first call has side effects that you cannot allow unless the second method also exists. Inspecting the object instead of having it run into the exception can usually solve this, but it's not necessarily very pretty.
- You might have to decide on how to treat the object in a way that does not depend on a particular method; for example, you may want to treat `unicode` and `string` objects differently.
- The objects might implement a method of the same name, but with different meanings - `hero.save(hostage)` and `file.save(filename)` are completely unrelated things, but the method names happen to collide, so just checking whether a method called `save` exists can yield false positives.

And then there's the situation where you have to decide on a code path based on more than one object; you can certainly work your way out using the self-describing method approach, or by testing relevant attributes of all the objects, but sometimes, `instanceof` is just easier to write, more readable, and more concise, in other words, the pragmatic choice.

Comment: There's a variant on the second approach which can be used in e.g. Java: try an explicit cast and be ready to catch the `ClassCastException`. It's probably open for debate whether this is really just hiding an `instanceof` check behind syntactic sugar.

Comment: Why not have the method `foo()` in `BaseBaz` (with `BaseBaz` implementing `Fooable`). The implementation of `foo()` in `BaseBaz` would throw `NotFooableException`. Then you could save the `null` check in `runFooOnBaz()`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Yes, I am aware of that. C# has an ever nicer way using the `as` operator, which basically does a try-cast that returns `null` when the cast is invalid.

Comment: @Giorgio: First of all, because I don't like stub methods, which is what `BaseBaz`'s implementation of `foo` would be. Second, I would have to have `BaseBaz` implement `Fooable`, but that would be a lie, because not all Bazzes are fooable, and it would move the is-fooable check from compile time (give me a compiler error when I naively try to use a Baz as a Fooable) to run-time (throw an exception when fooing a Baz that isn't *really* fooable). And third, throwing an exception is only one viable response, and I don't want to hard-code it.

Comment: @tdammers: Ok, I think I understand, you want to have the `throw new NotFooableException()` inside `runFooOnBaz()` and possibly choose some other option later.

Answer (score 0):

While instanceof should be avoided some Java interfaces require it as part of their contract.

For example: javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler.

It defines:

```
void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException
```

Callback is an interface with no methods so the only way to differentiate different types of Callback objects is using instanceof. The documentation for CallbackHandler.handle() encourages using instanceof.

Comment: instanceof should not be avoided, it should rather be used wisely, iow only where appropriate. Just like everything else.

Comment: Preference should be given to an object oriented solution and so instanceof should be used wisely. However sometimes there is no way to avoid it as in the example of the java API that requires it.